# how populate textview with specific column/row from sqlite database

Tags: android, sqlite

how to get a data in  KEY_NAME from my database(in DbHelper) into TextView("txtSchedName")? and after i retrieve the name its ID will also display in TextView("txtID")?

**DbHelper**

```
package com.example.dn;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

public class DbHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    static String DATABASE_NAME="patientdata";
    public static final String TABLE_NAME="patient";
    public static final String KEY_ID="id";
    public static final String KEY_NAME="pname";
    public static final String KEY_AGE="page";
    public static final String KEY_GENDER="pgender";
    public static final String KEY_ADDRESS="paddress";
    public static final String KEY_CONTACT="pcontact";

    private SQLiteDatabase mDb;

    public DbHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, 1);

    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        String CREATE_TABLE="CREATE TABLE "+TABLE_NAME+" ("+KEY_ID+" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, " +
                ""+KEY_NAME+" TEXT, "+KEY_AGE+" TEXT, "+KEY_GENDER+" TEXT, "+KEY_ADDRESS+" TEXT, "+KEY_CONTACT+" TEXT)";
        db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE);

    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "+TABLE_NAME);
        onCreate(db);

    }

    public void openDataBase() {
         //Open the database       
        String myPath = DATABASE_NAME + TABLE_NAME;      
        SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);     
        }
    //latest created
    public Cursor displayPatient() {

          Cursor mCursor = mDb.query(TABLE_NAME, new String[] {KEY_ID,
          KEY_NAME,KEY_AGE,KEY_CONTACT,KEY_GENDER,KEY_ADDRESS},
            null, null, null, null, null);

          if (mCursor != null) {
           mCursor.moveToLast();
          }
          return mCursor;
         }

    /*cur */
    public List<String> getAllLabels(){
        List<String> labels = new ArrayList<String>();

        // Select All Query
        String selectQuery = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_NAME;

        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery,null);

        // looping through all rows and adding to list
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                labels.add(cursor.getString(0));
            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }

        // closing connection
        cursor.close();
        db.close();

        // returning labels
        return labels;
    }



    }
```

**Schedule_DB_Helper**

```
package com.example.dn;

import android.content.Context;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

public class Schedule_DB_Helper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    static String DATABASE_NAME="patient_schedule";
    public static final String TABLE_NAME="schedule";
    public static final String KEY_ID="ID";
    public static final String KEY_NAME="NAME";
    public static final String KEY_DATE="DATE";
    public static final String KEY_TIME="TIME";
    //public static final String KEY_NOTI="NOTI";

    public Schedule_DB_Helper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, 1);

    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        String CREATE_TABLE="CREATE TABLE "+TABLE_NAME+" ("+KEY_ID+" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, " +
                ""+KEY_NAME+" TEXT,"+KEY_DATE+" TEXT, "+KEY_TIME+" TEXT)";
        db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE);

    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "+TABLE_NAME);
        onCreate(db);

    }

}
```

**AddSchedule**

```
/* ©muhammad dn version 1.0 
 * created 2015
 * run in 2 threads*/

package com.example.dn;


import java.util.Calendar;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.DatePickerDialog;
import android.app.TimePickerDialog;
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.DatePicker;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.TimePicker;
import android.database.Cursor;

public class AddSchedule extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
private Button btn_save;
private EditText name,datee, timee ; //gender_n_u
private Schedule_DB_Helper schedHelper;
private SQLiteDatabase dataBase;
private String id,sName,sDate,sTime;
private boolean isUpdate;
private Spinner spin;

//prprivate ArrayList<String> sched_name = new ArrayList<String>();pinner Notifications List
String []notifications = {"5minutes", "10minutes","20minutes","30minutes","1hours"};
//Spinner spin;
String Notifications;
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
// Variable for storing current date and time
private int mYear, mMonth, mDay, mHour, mMinute;
String am_pm = "";

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_add_schedule);

        spin=(Spinner)findViewById(R.id.Notification_spinner);
        adapter=new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line,notifications);
        spin.setAdapter(adapter);

        btn_save=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_save);
        name=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.txtSchedName);
        datee=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.txtSchedDate1);
        timee=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.txtSchedTime);

        datee.setOnClickListener(this);
        timee.setOnClickListener(this);
        btn_save.setOnClickListener(this);
        name.setOnClickListener(this);

      //add new record
            findViewById(R.id.btnAddSchedule).setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                public void onClick(View v) {

                    Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                            AddPatient.class);
                    i.putExtra("update", false);
                    startActivity(i);

                }
            });

       isUpdate=getIntent().getExtras().getBoolean("update");
        if(isUpdate)
        {
            id=getIntent().getExtras().getString("ID");
            sName=getIntent().getExtras().getString("NAME");
            sDate=getIntent().getExtras().getString("DATE");
            sTime=getIntent().getExtras().getString("TIME");
            //sNoti=getIntent().getExtras().getString("NOTI");//

            name.setText(sName);
            datee.setText(sDate);
            timee.setText(sTime);
            //spin.setTag(sNoti);//

        }
          schedHelper=new Schedule_DB_Helper(this);
    }

    //©muhammad saveButton click event 
    public void onClick(View v) { //\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\

        if (v == name) {
            DbHelper dbHelperInstance = new DbHelper(this); 
            Cursor cursor = dbHelperInstance.displayPatient();
            if(cursor != null) {
                EditText pName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtSchedName);
                pName.setText(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DbHelper.KEY_NAME)));
            }
        }
    //date and time picking**************************************
        if (v == datee) {

            // Process to get Current Date
            final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
            mYear = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
            mMonth = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
            mDay = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

                // Launch Date Picker Dialog
                DatePickerDialog dpd = new DatePickerDialog(this,
                        new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {

                            @Override
                            public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year,
                                    int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
                                // Display Selected date in textbox
                                datee.setText(dayOfMonth + "-"
                                        + (monthOfYear + 1) + "-" + year);

                            }
                        }, mYear, mMonth, mDay);
                dpd.show();
        }
        if (v == timee) {

            // Process to get Current Time
            final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
            mHour = c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
            mMinute = c.get(Calendar.MINUTE);


                // Launch Time Picker Dialog
                TimePickerDialog tpd = new TimePickerDialog(this,
                        new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {

                            @Override
                            public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay,
                                    int minute ) {
                                //Adding AM:PM in Time
                                if (c.get(Calendar.AM_PM) == Calendar.AM)
                                    am_pm = "AM";
                                else if (c.get(Calendar.AM_PM) == Calendar.PM)
                                    am_pm = "PM";
                                // Display Selected time in textbox
                                timee.setText(hourOfDay + ":" + minute+" "+am_pm);
                            }
                        }, mHour, mMinute, false);
                tpd.show();
        }

    //saving data

        if (v == btn_save) {

        sName=name.getText().toString().trim();
        sDate=datee.getText().toString().trim();
        sTime=timee.getText().toString().trim();
        //  sNoti=spin.getTag().toString().trim();

        if(sName.length()>0 && sDate.length()>0 && sTime.length()>0)
        {
            saveData();
        }
        else
        {
            AlertDialog.Builder alertBuilder=new AlertDialog.Builder(AddSchedule.this);
            alertBuilder.setTitle("Invalid Data");
            alertBuilder.setMessage("Please, Enter valid data");
            alertBuilder.setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                dialog.cancel();

                }
            });
            alertBuilder.create().show();}
        }}


    //©muhammad Saving Data to SQLite 
    private void saveData(){
        dataBase= schedHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues values=new ContentValues();

        values.put(Schedule_DB_Helper.KEY_NAME, sName);
        values.put(Schedule_DB_Helper.KEY_DATE, sDate );
        values.put(Schedule_DB_Helper.KEY_TIME, sTime );
        //values.put(Schedule_DB_Helper.KEY_NOTI, sNoti );

        System.out.println("");
        if(isUpdate)
        {    
            //update database with new data 
            dataBase.update(Schedule_DB_Helper.TABLE_NAME, values, Schedule_DB_Helper.KEY_ID+"="+id, null);
        }
        else
        {
            //insert data into database
            dataBase.insert(Schedule_DB_Helper.TABLE_NAME, null, values);
        }
        //close database
        dataBase.close();
        finish();


    }
}
```

**activity_add_schedule**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/note1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:background="#222222"
        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/note"
        android:drawablePadding="10dp"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:paddingRight="10dp"
        android:paddingTop="10dp"
        android:text="@string/note1"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:textSize="12sp" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/txtSchedName"
        android:layout_width="260dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/pname"
        android:layout_marginLeft="14dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="" >

        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/txtSchedName"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/pname"
        android:contentDescription="@string/cd1"
        android:src="@drawable/search" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/txtSchedTime"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/TextView02"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/txtSchedDate1"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/txtSchedDate1"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="@string/hint7"
        android:nextFocusDown="@+id/btn_save" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnAddSchedule"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/pname"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/pname"
        android:layout_below="@+id/note1"
        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/add_new"
        android:drawablePadding="10dp"
        android:onClick="addPatient"
        android:text="@string/button_addPatient" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_save"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/done"
        android:drawablePadding="-40dp"
        android:text="@string/button_done"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        android:width="163dp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btncancel"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/cancel"
        android:drawablePadding="-30dp"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
        android:onClick="cancel"
        android:text="@string/button_cancel"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        android:width="164dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/pname"
        android:layout_width="291dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/txtSchedName"
        android:layout_below="@+id/btnAddSchedule"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:text="@string/pname"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:textColor="#686868"
        android:textSize="12sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/TextView03"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/btncancel"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/TextView02"
        android:layout_marginBottom="34dp"
        android:text="@string/textView6"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:textColor="#686868"
        android:textSize="14sp" />

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/Notification_spinner"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/btn_save"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/TextView01" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/TextView02"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/Notification_spinner"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/TextView01"
        android:layout_marginBottom="26dp"
        android:text="@string/textView5"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:textColor="#686868"
        android:textSize="14sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/TextView01"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/txtSchedTime"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/txtSchedName"
        android:layout_marginBottom="21dp"
        android:text="@string/textView4"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:textColor="#686868"
        android:textSize="14sp" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/txtSchedDate1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/btn_save"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/TextView01"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="@string/hint6"
        android:nextFocusDown="@+id/textTIME" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/TextView04"
        android:layout_width="291dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/txtSchedName"
        android:layout_below="@+id/txtSchedName"
        android:layout_marginTop="17dp"
        android:text="ID"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:textColor="#686868"
        android:textSize="12sp" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/txtID"
        android:layout_width="260dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/TextView04"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/TextView04"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/TextView04"
        android:layout_marginLeft="35dp"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/txtSchedDate1"
        android:ems="10" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: This is an official platform, try to post in a formal language :) .

Comment: What is the problem exactly? Do you get any errors while trying to set the result of your query to your TextView or you don't know how to retrieve data from your database?

Comment: I dont know how to retrieve data from my database, can you help me?

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example from an app of mine where I wanted to pull certain information from my `SQLite` database to instantiate a new custom object. I pulled the data based on `UUID`. You'll most likely have some other way of identifying which column to pull data from.

```
// Member variable for selecting all columns in my table
private String[] allColumns = {  MyObjectDatabaseHelper.COLUMN_ONE
                                 MyObjectDatabaseHelper.COLUMN_TWO,
                                 MyObjectDatabaseHelper.COLUMN_THREE,
                                 MyObjectDatabaseHelper.COLUMN_FOUR,
                                 MyObjectDatabaseHelper.COLUMN_FIVE,
                                 MyObjectDatabaseHelper.COLUMN_SIX,
                                 MyObjectDatabaseHelper.COLUMN_SEVEN,
                                 MyObjectDatabaseHelper.COLUMN_EIGHT};

public MyObject getSession(UUID mUUID)
{
    db = dbHelper.getReadableDatabase();

    Cursor cursor = db.query(MyObjectDatabaseHelper.TABLE_MYOBJECT,
                             allColumns,
                             MyObjectDatabaseHelper.COLUMN_ONE + "=?",
                             new String [] {mUUID.toString()},
                             null,
                             null,
                             null,
                             null);

    if (cursor != null)
    {
        cursor.moveToFirst();
    }

    MyObject mMyObject = new MyObject(UUID.fromString(cursor.getString(1)),
                             cursor.getString(2),
                             cursor.getString(3),
                             cursor.getString(4),
                             cursor.getString(5),
                             cursor.getString(6),
                             cursor.getInt(7));

    cursor.close();

    return mMyObject;
}
```

In this example, I selected all the columns in the table, then used all those values in the constructor for my custom object. What you can do is only select one column, if that's all you need, and then use that value to set the text in your `TextView`.

You might do something like this:

```
public getColumnText()
{
   String text = cursor.getString(column);
   return text;
}
```

For more information on `query(...)`, see [here](http://developer.android.com/intl/zh-CN/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html).

> public Cursor query (String table, String[] columns, String selection,
>   String[] selectionArgs, String groupBy, String having, String orderBy,
>   String limit)

For more `SQLite` tutorials, see below:

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_sqlite_database.htm

http://www.androidhive.info/2011/11/android-sqlite-database-tutorial/

http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidSQLite/article.html#overview_sqlite